# docker still return self-signed SSL cert error after ignore the TLS unauthorized 0

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, axios

I am working on a POC for the nodejs container to call another IP's web application for testing.
The application working fine in the local development env, and I deployed the app on SUSE15 for the final testing.
The api would like to call:

```
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
})
axios.defaults.httpsAgent = httpsAgent;

class ansibleService {
  public async findJobStatusById(jobId: number){
try{
  let res = await axios.get(URL+'/api/v2/jobs/'+jobId ,{headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic '+basicAuth}}, {httpsAgent});
  console.log("status code: ", res.status)
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data
}catch(err){
  console.log(err)
  return err
}
```

The app was built, however, the API call is not working and returns 503 error

```
Error: Request failed with status code 503\n    at createError (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:293:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21
```

Coz it just a POC, i am trying to ignore the TLS cert and adding the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` and `rejectUnauthorized: false,` in side the code.

As the result, the app is still returning error 503 with details:

```
  '</head><body id="ERR_SECURE_CONNECT_FAIL">\n' +
  '<div id="titles">\n' +
  '<h1>ERROR</h1>\n' +
  '<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>\n' +
  '</div>\n' +
  '<hr>\n' +
  '\n' +
  '<div id="content">\n' +
  '<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="https://10.194.113.123/api/v2/jobs/11507">https://10.194.113.123/api/v2/jobs/11507</a></p>\n' +
  '\n' +
  '<blockquote id="error">\n' +
  '<p><b>Failed to establish a secure connection to 10.194.113.123</b></p>\n' +
  '</blockquote>\n' +
  '\n' +
  '<div id="sysmsg">\n' +
  '<p>The system returned:</p>\n' +
  '<blockquote id="data">\n' +
  '<pre>(71) Protocol error (TLS code: X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT)</pre>\n' +
  '<p>Self-signed SSL Certificate: /CN=abc.corpdev.com</p>\n' +
  '</blockquote>\n' +
  '</div>\n' +
  '\n' +
  '<p>This proxy and the remote host failed to negotiate a mutually acceptable security settings for handling your request. It is possible that the remote host does not support secure connections, or the proxy is not satisfied with the host security credentials.</p>\n'
```

**Is that any config missed/incorrect on the docker build/run? Please let me know where am i incorrect for the deployment if have**

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `httpsAgent` as an additional argument, but it should be placed in the request config object:

```
let res = await axios.get(URL+'/api/v2/jobs/'+jobId, {
 headers: {
   'Authorization': 'Basic '+basicAuth
 },
 httpsAgent
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! I updated the axios request but returned the same message, wondering if the container network cannot access the internet.

Comment: The error suggests that it's able to connect, it's just having an issue with the certificate. Are you rebuilding the Docker container after every change?